# react-router mounts the wrong component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm writing a React-on-Rails (v. 5) app and am running into an issue. When I visit the path `accounts/:account_id/letters/new`, React-Router is mounting the `EmailShowComponent`, when I want it to mount the `EmailSendComponent`.

This is my app.js file:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/accounts/:id" component={AccountShowContainer} />
  <Route path="/accounts/:account_id/letters/:id" component={EmailShowComponent} />
  <Route path="/accounts/:account_id/letters/new" component={EmailSendComponent} />
</Router>
```

This is my main.js file:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

$(function(){
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
  )
});
```

And I've placed `"<div id="app">"` tags inside each of the relevant html pages that generate those paths for the router.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The ordering of your routes; nothing says `new` isn't a valid ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the path `/accounts/:account_id/letters/new` also satisfies the path `/accounts/:account_id/letters/:id`. The difference being `id` gets to be `"new"`.

To fix this, simply swap the order of your routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/accounts/:id" component={AccountShowContainer} />
  <Route path="/accounts/:account_id/letters/new" component={EmailSendComponent} />
  <Route path="/accounts/:account_id/letters/:id" component={EmailShowComponent} />
</Router>
```

---

For more info, check out [the Precedence section](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#precedence) from the official docs:

> Finally, the routing algorithm attempts to match routes in the order
>   they are defined, top to bottom. So, when you have two sibling routes
>   you should be sure the first doesn't match all possible `path`s that can
>   be matched by the later sibling. For example, **don't** do this:
>
> ```
> <Route path="/comments" ... />
> <Redirect from="/comments" ... />
> ```